# Removing horizontal line in ms word footer

Tags: ms-word

Can anyone tell me how to remove the horizontal line in ms-word footer

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Lvz8JqiE5Ot2aX88IA4l7BCNGoqZ8Q7z/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This is not a programming question and, as such, is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Questions on general usage of Microsoft Word should be asked on an appropriate end-use forum (e.g., MS Answers).